# How do I import modules: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this simple Node.js script which imports a service to use:

```
import {getProjects} from "./models/external/services/Service";

async function main() {
  const projects = await getProjects()
  console.log(projects)
}
```

My tsconfig.json is configured like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "es2022",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I then have the following in my package.json:

```
 ...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "start": "tsc && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  ...
```

So I run `npm run build` followed by `npm run start` but get the error:

> node:internal/errors:490
> ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
> ^
>
> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
> '/home/Project/dist/models/external/services/Service' imported
> from /home/Project/dist/index.js

Any ideas on solving this?

UPDATE: The issue is that I need to add .js at the end of the Service.
e.g. `import {getProjects} from "./models/external/services/Service.js";`

Is there anyway to not need to do this?